# why for SQLCOM_UPDATE_MULTI, it lock other table with lock_s (INNODB )

Tags: mysql, sql-update, innodb, rowlocking

innodb READ-COMMITTED:

table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` ( `key1` int(11) NOT NULL, `key2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`key1`) ) ENGINE=innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `test1` ( `key1` int(11) NOT NULL, `key2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`key1`) ) ENGINE=innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into test values(1,1);
insert into test1 values(1,1);
```

case 1:

```
connection 1:
begin;
update test set key2=111 where key1 in (select key1 from test1);
// test1 lock with LOCK_NONE (no lock); (sql_command:SQLCOM_UPDATE )

then 
connection 2:
update test1 set key2=9994;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.091 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

case 2:

```
connection 1:
begin;
update test a inner join (select key1 from test1) b on a.key1=b.key1 set a.key2=111;
// test1 lock with LOCK_S (sql_command:SQLCOM_UPDATE_MULTI )

then 
connection 2:
update test1 set key2=9994;
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

in ha_innobase::store_lock, only SQLCOM_UPDATE was processed.

why SQLCOM_UPDATE_MULTI can‘t be LOCK_NONE ?,but SQLCOM_UPDATE with LOCK_NONE .

Comment: "Sharding" implies two separate _instances_ of MySQL.  The code sounds like 2 _connections_ battling over 2 tables.

Comment: change table name ,‘sharding’ is just a name, no meaning